# how to load url image in image view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.scri8e.com/effects/FL0WERZ/PNG/ir09.png"];
    data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url ];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];
    imageview.image=img;
    }
```

above is my code but it does not load  the image in image view

Comment: You have to wait. All this is synchronous.

Comment: check your internet connection. this code working. i checked

Comment: Look for lazy download another wise it stuck your view ,according to image size data.

Comment: is your imageview is in xib or taken programmatically?

Comment: Aaaaa:    imageview is in xib

Comment: Complete source code over here : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/load-image-from-existing-location-and.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) library it will help you download images and display in the imageview.

Answer (score 1):

The same code working for me fine !!!!!!

> Please check the Internet Connection.
>
> Please check the `NSData *data`  size
>
> Please check the UIImageView Size
>
> Please check it hided by some other controls
>
> Please check it added properly to your View
>
> Please check its Content View

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.scri8e.com/effects/FL0WERZ/PNG/ir09.png"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url ];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];
self.imageview.image=img;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are taken imageview directly  in xib, than just check connection  in connection inspector.

Answer (score 0):

use [EgoImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading) instead of ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *mainimg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[xmlDataDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"eg.main.img1"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainimg];
NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:image];
```

Try this for parsed url..

So simple..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *url_Img1 = @"http://www.scri8e.com/effects/FL0WERZ/PNG";
    NSString *url_Img2 = @"ir09.png";

    NSString *url_Img_FULL = [url_Img1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:url_Img2];

    NSLog(@"Show url_Img_FULL: %@",url_Img_FULL);
    _view_Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url_Img_FULL]]];

}
```